# How to create a pytest marker for duplicate code

Tags: pytest

I have several unit tests in my pytest suite with the exact same boilerplate:

```
@use_cache
def test_something(self):
    _check_cache_connection()

    ...

    cache.clear()
```

Instead of copying this boilerplate into dozens of tests, I'd love to create a custom pytest marker called `cache` to do this for me. So the test would look like this:

```
@pyyest.mark.cache
def test_something(self):
    ...
```

So far, I've come up with the following:

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def _use_cache(request):
    marker = request.node.get_closest_marker("cache")

    with ExitStack() as stack:
        if marker:
            stack.enter_context(use_cache())
            _check_cache_connection()

        yield

        if marker:
            cache.clear()
```

This seems to be working correctly but I feel like there may be a better way to do it. Does this look okay or does someone have a better implementation?

Comment: Why not use the fixture directly where needed instead of going through the hoop to check for a marker?

Comment: Because my codebase is using the Django `TestCase` base class so I can't use pytest fixtures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid `ExitStack` and multiple `if marker` by separating (auto-use) `_use_cache_marker` and the actual `_use_cache`, calling [`request.getfixturevalue`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.FixtureRequest.getfixturevalue) in the former to run the latter:

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def _use_cache_marker(request):
    marker = request.node.get_closest_marker("cache")
    if marker:
        request.getfixturevalue("_use_cache")


@pytest.fixture()
def _use_cache():
    with use_cache():
        _check_cache_connection()
        yield
        cache.clear()
```

pytest-django does this for the `django_db` marker: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/blob/1ad013e4bc612d89dcade9e0427c198566f05006/pytest_django/plugin.py#L460-L465

Answer (score -1):

Put the boilerplate code in a separate function and parametrize it with function arguments.

Then you can simply call this function from each test with suitable parameters.

Works perfectly.